# Exact format of xargs -I parameters?

Tags: xargs

Indeed, I would like to know the exact format of  '-I' parameter (string, variant, etc.)

for a script like this,

```
seq 15 | xargs -I num

seq 15 | xargs -I num bash -c "echo num"
```

will work

The 'num' here I regard as a parameter for the execution of the script in bash -c ""
while I'm not sure about the format of the num when it's introduced into the bash

Try

```
seq 15 | xargs -I num bash -c "name=num; echo name"
```

regarded it as a string while failed.

Try

```
seq 15 | xargs -I num bash -c "name=num; echo $name"
```

also didn't work.

I just want to try the multithreading with `--max-procs` to limit the threads number, while I'm not quite sure about such problem while I guess maybe it's something about the '=' thing.
How can I get this to work as I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`num` is just replaced by each string of digits output from seq.

Your attempts to assign to `name` where correct but to display you have escape the `$`:

```
seq 15 | xargs -I num bash -c "name=num; echo \$name"
```

if you would have tried:

```
name=hallo; seq 15 | xargs -I num bash -c "name=num; echo $name"
```

you probably would have noticed.

Answer (score 2):

Anthon has already explained your error. I would like to add that there is a better solution for the `bash -c ''` case:

```
seq 15 | xargs -L 1 bash -c 'name=$1; echo $name' foo
```

This it better because it is more flexible. You may pass more than one parameter (probably not useful with `seq` input).